# math expression on ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to put the expression

a x b^.5 x c^.8

on a ggplot label

here is the code:

```
library(latex2exp)

    df = data.frame(x= 1:5,y = 1:5)
    ggplot(df,aes( x= x ,y = y))+geom_point()+
      geom_text(x = 1 , y =1, label = TeX('$ a \\times b^.5 \\times c^.8$'))
```

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


tex_var <- '$ a \\times b^.5 \\times c^.8$'

# to label each point with the LaTEX expression
df = data.frame(x= 1:5,y = 1:5, z = )
ggplot(df,aes( x= x ,y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes( y = y+.25),label = TeX(tex_var, "text"))


# to put it as a label to the whole plot
ggplot(df,aes( x= x ,y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = TeX(tex_var, "text")) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", color="red"))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi - I get an error Error in stats::complete.cases(df[, vars, drop = FALSE]) : 
  invalid 'type' (expression) of argument

Comment: using R 3.5.0 on Mac OS High Sierra v 10.13.6

Comment: had to do ...label = TeX(tex_var, "character"),parse=TRUE)